# Fixing Model/Column mapping in Code First/EF6

Tags: entity-framework

First of all, I shot myself in the foot.  I'm building a test application (this is work related, not school btw.)  I have a model with a foreign key property

```
Home_TeamId
```

That mapped to a column called

`Home_TeamId` in my database.  Everything was happy until I refactored everything to use ID instead of Id.  I didn't notice the Migration added a column called Home_TeamID1 and is storing the data there instead of Home_TeamId (where I want it.)

So what I would like to do is:

1. Drop the column Home_TeamID1 (No problem, I can do that.)
2. Rename Home_TeamId to Home_TeamID. (No problem, I can do that.)
3. Tell EF to write the data to the original column.

I've read how to use database mappings in the DbContext, but that isn't what I'm trying to do either (i.e., this is a one-time thing, not something I need to do every time the app runs.) (BTW, there is no .edmx file either.)

So that's the question -- how do I tell EF to write the Home_TeamID field in the domain model to the Home_TeamID column in the table?

I should add that I've done another migration since then so it's not (necessarily) so easy as to just target back one revision.

Edit 1:
EF was writing the same Team ID to both the Home_TeamID and Home_TeamID1 columns, although it had made the ..ID1 file the foreign key.

I've looked everywhere on my project for the text "ID1" (both as text and as binary Unicode) and the only places it shows up are in the *_migration.cs files.

In the meantime, I've tried Steps 1 and 2 above.  And now (as expected) I get:

```
InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException HResult=-2146232060
Message=Invalid column name 'Home_TeamID1'.
Invalid column name 'Visitors_TeamID1'.
```

Edit 2:

I tried this:

1. Create a brand new (blank database)
2. Excluded all the .cs files in the Migrations from the project
3. add-migration InitialRecreate
4. Looked in the resulting .cs file and removed any reference to ID1.  (In fact, there were two...where did they come from??)
5. Looked in the project and found 0 references to ID1.
6. Update-database
7. Ran the project
8. Invalid column name 'Home_TeamID1'.

So obviously the problem isn't the database itself.

Comment: The model property has been renamed, but the original database column has not? Is your database actually case sensitive?

Comment: No, what happened was that I wound up with both cases somehow in the model, but since the database is not case sensitive, it threw SQL errors (adding the same parameter twice.)

Answer (score 0):

It was a case of the software outsmarting the human.  In my "higher-level" GameSummary class, I had:

```
public int GameSummaryID { get; set; }
public int Home_TeamID { get; set; }
public virtual Team Home { get; set; }
public int Visitors_TeamID { get; set; }
public virtual Team Visitors { get; set; }
```

And in the Team class I had:

```
public int TeamID { get; set; }
```

So EF was creating two columns, one for Home_TeamID (the field Home_TeamID in the GameSummary class) and one for Home_TeamID (the foreign key for the navigation property that pointed to the Team object).  The solution:

```
public int GameSummaryID { get; set; }
public int HomeTeamID { get; set; }
public virtual Team Home { get; set; }
public int VisitorsTeamID { get; set; }
public virtual Team Visitors { get; set; }
```